# Trying to add ajax to RoR app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, debugging, ruby-on-rails-3

I get an `ActionView::MissingTemplate` error trying to add ajax to a Twitter-like micropost controller.  Here's the full error:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template microposts/create with {:handlers=>[:rhtml, :erb, :rxml, :builder, :rjs], :locale=>[:en, :en], :formats=>[:js, :html]} in view paths "/rubyprograms/sample_app/app/views"):
app/controllers/microposts_controller.rb:9:in `create'
```

Here's my `create` method. Btw line 9 is the `respond_to` line:

```
  def create
@micropost  = current_user.microposts.build(params[:micropost])
if @micropost.save
  flash[:success] = "Micropost created!"
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to root_path }
    format.js
  end
else
  @feed_items = []
  render 'pages/home'
 end
end
```

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE: I have my .rjs file in my `views` folder. Is that where it should be? Should the file have a specific name? It's currently called `create.rjs`

Answer (score 0):

The `create.rjs` should be under `app/views/microposts`

Answer (score 0):

The name of the file should be

```
create.js.erb
```

Then in your controller you must use a:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js # view create.js.erb
end
```

Answer (score -1):

In order to use rjs in rails 3, use ***

> prototype-rails

*** gem